# I'm looking to add syntax color in emacs for global variable, define, local variable in a func like eclipse

Tags: c, emacs, elisp

I'm looking to add syntax coloring in Emacs for global variables, defines, local variables in a function.

For example, local variables would be green, globals would be orange, and defines would be blue, like this picture:

[image: syntax highlighting example]

Comment: The answer will be major mode specific. That looks like C?

Comment: yes is it. C. what is major mode?

Comment: ["Every buffer possesses a major mode, which determines the editing behavior of Emacs while that buffer is current."](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Major-Modes.html) You may want to do the Emacs tutorial. In Emacs, press `Ctrl`+`h`, then let go, then press `t`.

Comment: ok like c-mode or c++-mode. i use c-mode actualy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is - you cannot.

Emacs highlighting works on regular expressions, not on syntax analysis.
E.g., `foo_t` is highlighted as a type because of the `_t` suffix (`int` et al are explicitly mentioned in the regexps).

To do better `emacs` must either parse the C syntax (prohibitively expensive) or talk to a C compiler (`clang`, because `gcc` does not reveal its parse tree).

See, e.g.,

- [emacs-clang-complete-async](https://github.com/Golevka/emacs-clang-complete-async)
- [clang-completion-mode.el](https://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/utils/clang-completion-mode.el)
- [AutoComplete](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoComplete)

These talk about completion, but they are using the same tools that you need and you can relatively easily extend them to do what you need.